# CSS boxed template won't box

Tags: css

I have a problem with 'boxing' my template.
The top-navigation is boxed (max-width:1600px, margin:0 auto). And perfectly aligned in the center of the page, as it should.

The main content is also boxed, but not for the 100% (within the 1600px).
Its like filling up only 80% of the row. So its in disbalance.

You can see it for youself trough https://watmoetenwedoen.nl/blog/

Here is my code, hopefully you guys see something which I miss!

header.inc

```
<div id="topnav">
<div class="row ashgrey">
    <div class="top boxed">
        <!-- LOGO -->
        <a href="../"><div class="logo col-2"><?php echo "$header->logo" ?></div></a> <!-- end logo -->

        <!-- NAV -->
        <div class="nav-top col-8"> 
            <ul class='topnav' role='navigation'><?php
                $children = $home->children();
                $children->prepend($home);
                foreach($children as $child) {
                    if($child->id == $page->rootParent->id) {
                        echo "<li class='current' aria-current='true'><span class='visually-hidden'>Current page: </span><a href='$child->url'>$child->title</a></li>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<li><a href='$child->url'>$child->title</a></li>";
                    }
                }
            ?></ul>
        </div> <!-- end nav-top col-4 -->
    </div> <!-- /top -->
</div> <!-- /row -->
```

The pages showing the 'main' content
The code is as following

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content boxed col-12">
            <h1><?php echo $page->title; ?></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content boxed col-12">
            <h2><?php echo $page->content_title; ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $page->text; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With the css

```
    #main {
    padding-top: 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    clear: both;
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

.boxed {
    padding:0% 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    max-width:1600px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.row [class^="col"] {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5rem 2%;
  min-height: 0.125rem;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 96%;
  float:left;
}
```

I've spend my whole afternoon to solve this but I couldn't figure it out on my own. So thats why I ask you guys for a favor. Hope you can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you want. What do you mean by "boxed"?

Comment: Thanks @technophyle, by boxed I mean the wrapper. So the screen is 100%, the wrapper (box) is 100% with a max-width of 1600px.

Answer (score 1):

At least here https://watmoetenwedoen.nl/blog/ the wrapper is correct. But the content is not stretched to 100%. This is due to the class col-4 which should have a width of 33.3333%.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher, yea, thats correct, but 3 times 33.3333% should make 100% right? And it still makes about 80% of the width.

Comment: because on your site col-4 has a width of 29.33% at @media only screen and (min-width: 45em) coming from [link](https://watmoetenwedoen.nl/site/templates/styles/simple-grid.css)

Comment: Pffff thaaaaanks Christopher, you're the mannnnn!!!!! Danggg, it took me so long. Thanks helping me out!